# C: MD5 gives garbage as result

Tags: c, macos, hash, md5

I'm using [Peter Deutsch's implementation of MD5](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmd5-rfc/files/) to implement a simple password check. I use it this way:

```
md5_state_t md;
char *in = "Hello World";
char *out[16];

md5_init(&md);
md5_append(&md, in, strlen(in));
md5_finish(&md, out);

printf("In:  %s\n", in);
printf("Out: %s\n", out);
```

Problem is, that I get a result like this:

```
In:  Hello World
Out: ?
??d?uA????.??
```

Does anyone has an idea whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An MD5 hash is a binary blob of 16 bytes. You cannot print that as a string. Print it e.g. in a hex representation:

```
md5_state_t md;
char *in = "Hello World";
char out[16];
int i;

md5_init(&md);
md5_append(&md, in, strlen(in));
md5_finish(&md, out);

printf("In:  %s\n", in);
printf("Out: ");
for(i = 0; i < 16: i++) 
   printf("%02X", out[i]);
puts("");
```

Note that the above changes `out` to be a char as well, it can not be a char*

Comment: Works, great. Thanks.
I understand, that it's a binary, returned by the function. But I want the data to be stored in ascii text, just like the PHP md5() does. I played around a little but found that a lot of bits in the returned blob are just ff's - so no printable sign according to ascii. Is there any general offset, e.g. PHP md5() uses?

Comment: Okay, found it by myself. Just make out[] unsigned. m)